# How can I format money in RainMeter?

Tags: rainmeter

I'm attempting to take a number like `5342.9` and would like to format it into USD.  Ideally the outcome would be `$5,342.90`.  My Measure is:

```
[MeasureUSDValue]
Measure=Plugin
Plugin=WebParser
URL=[MeasureBTC]
StringIndex=1

[MeterColumnValue]
Meter=String
MeasureName=MeasureUSDValue
NumOfDecimals=2
Text=$%1
```

[NumOfDecimals](https://docs.rainmeter.net/manual/meters/string/#NumOfDecimals) appears to be a thing, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

$ is special char of regex for end of string, use `\$` for USD sign

Comment: I've adjusted this to not use regex for simplicity

Comment: Also, unfortunately in Rainmeter that doesn't work, the dollar sign isn't appended - `Substitute="(.+?)":"\$\1"`